# Writing API: what a handle should be

Tags: c, api, design-patterns, handle

Let's suppose we're writing a library implementing some API. The lib creates some resources (connections/internal data structures/whatever) and returns a handle which then is used to make further calls.

**What are recommended ways to represent a handle?**

- Should it be a raw pointer to some internal data structure allocated
  while creating a session?
- If it is the case, how do I secure the lib in case API functions are
  called after `close` method which deallocates the data handle has
  pointed to?

If handle is an **abstract number** (like key in "handle"->"obj" map), won't it affect performance?

What other approaches are possible? Which one should I choose?

If anybody has worked on API's, could you share your experience on the subject?

The question is too wide and abstract, but currently I'm working on very similar task and just don't know how to tackle the problem.

I've been looking through `sqlite3` sources, their handle is just a pointer to dynamically allocated structure, they set some magic numbers while opening connection and closing it and checking validity of a handle consists in checking those magic numbers. Is it safe enough?

Answer (score 4):

I'd design the "close"-function to set the opaque pointer to `NULL`.

interface.h:

```
typedef struct handle_internals * Handle;

int handle_open(/* out */ Handle * phandle, ..);
int handle_close(/* in out */ Handle * phandle)

int handle_func1(Handle handle, ..);
...
```

implementation.c:

```
...

#include "interface.h"

...

struct handle_internals
{
  ...
}

int handle_open(Handle * phandle, ..)
{
  if (NULL == phandle)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    return -1;
  }

  *phandle = malloc(sizeof ** phandle);

  ...

  return 0;
}

int handle_close(Handle * phandle)
{
  if (NULL == phandle)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    return -1;
  }

  free(*phandle);
  *phandle = NULL;

  return 0;
}

int handle_func1(Handle handle, ..)
{
  if (NULL == handle)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    return -1;
  }

  ...

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So your `close` function takes the handle by address. Consider the following code: `Handle h1 = /*..*/;  Handle h2 = h1; handle_close(&h1); handle_func1(h2); /* oops */ `  obviously this is simplified but you can't depend on `close` to invalidate all aliases for a specific handle.

Comment: @Motti: This would invoke undefined behaviour and the program would sooner or later fail, as with any other misuse of invalid memory, yes. This is C. Lesson learned: Do not "copy" handles.

Comment: What I'm saying is that nulling in `close` gives a false sense of security.

Answer (score 3):

The question *"is it safe enough?"* depends on your application.

If it's a Sudoku solver running on your laptop then it's probably OK to have minimal or no handle verification.

If it's a controller for a self driving car then I would hope that you want to be very confident you're not working on garbage.

For most uses it's fine to use opaque pointers.

Comment: I was going to suggest using [opaque pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) too. You could set some fields inside the structure to `NULL` when `close` has been called and if later functions receive this, you can error out.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim the problem with that is that it means that you have to keep the structures around after closing the handle and can't `free` them.

Comment: @Motti What if we check if memory is readable before accessing it? And  keep some magic numbers or check if members are NULL as Noufal Ibrahim has suggested.

Comment: @olegst, freed memory is still readable (especially since the same address can be allocated to someone else after it's freed).

Answer (score 3):

A handle can be something as simple as an integer value assigned to maintain association between a process and an object, or the kernel.  Or it can be a pointer to a very large table, used by the kernel (or calling application, or API) to track (and provide)  process states, object states, memory usage, etc.
Not all APIs need handles, but there are many that do.  Maybe the first observation I would make is how many types of handles already exist in Windows programming alone, then ask what properties or qualities do *they* have, and why they are necessary in those scenarios.  Here is a short list of some common handle types in use for Windows programming:

***1)*** HWND  - Handle to a window.  Used to keep track of objects on the display
***2)*** HINSTANCE  - allows OS (kernal) to communicate with an instance of an application.
***3)*** HMENU - Used to display, or control a menu in an application.
***4)*** HANDLE - WINAPI generic handle.  Used to associate many objects, such as a handle to control a thread, for example.

All of these have in common the job of providing a logical link between kernel, application objects and processes and conveying relevant, contextual information between all of them.

In general, although handles are often defined as unsigned 32 bit values, they should never be treated like integers.  They are a unique value , and if edited, or used in any manipulation that could change its value, it can no longer be trusted as a link to the object is was created for.  A programmer should store a handle, but never modify it.

So, what are the ***specific needs for your API***?

*Should it be a raw pointer to some internal data structure allocated while creating a session?* 
You say *The lib creates some resources*.  If you have a need to track or control those resources, a handle to the object (a pointer to struct, or an array of struct for to support multiple processes) would be useful.

*how do I secure the lib in case API functions are called after close method*?
Design into your API:
1)  Your close method should set the handle object to 0, or NULL (depending on what type of object you have used)
2)  All public functions in your API should require a non-zero/non-NULL value for a handle.
3)  Provide a private function in your API to validate values passed as a handle for any API function is one that has been assigned. (check for non-null, or non-0.  Is the value passed an active handle?) Call this function at the top of all public API functions.

*If handle is an abstract number (like key in "handle"->"obj" map), won't it affect performance?*
I assume you are speaking of efficiencies connected to passing handle information via function arguments...
Regarding function arguments and performance, passing small values as function arguments is simply the cost of doing business, but for large objects, you can improve your throughput performance by passing a pointer to that object rather than passing the object itself.

Comment: "you are speaking of efficiencies connected to passing handle information via function arguments" - no, I'm speaking of look-up overhead. I was thinking of keeping internal map structure to track active handles (in order to implement smart handle validity check, not just "non-null/null"). But this idea seems clumsy to me, so I 'm curious if handle can be verified with the use of magic numbers: that is handle is a pointer to memory region with associated session/connection context and some of it's fields are set accordingly during creation/destruction.

Comment: Or rather: which solution is more feasible: to keep all data structures in a map and use key as a handle (and thus to know for sure if handle is valid), to set magic numbers in data structure and return pointer to it as a handle or just not to bother with this validity check and be satisfied with a simple null/non-null check.

Comment: @olegst - ***regarding*** _I was thinking of keeping internal map structure to track active handles [but that is clumsey]_. as  opposed to _...use of magic numbers: that is handle is a pointer to memory region with associated session/connection..._.  ***These two ideas are not mutually exclusive***.  A struct containing the handle value and all relevant information about that session can be thought of as a very accessible memory map of session information (handles, etc). ***...***

Comment: ***...*** You can either create a struct (using global `extern` scope in the declaration in a header file, and definition in a .c source somewhere else) or you can  declare the struct definition in a header, and define copies elsewhere, then pass the pointers to that struct around as arguments.  Either way works, both are considered efficient in application architectures, where memory usage is not tight.  In an embedded environment, with limited memory, I would (and often do) select the first method.  (One copy of the information-with global scope)

Answer (score 1):

When lacking a better idea, I would suggest using an opaque pointer to a struct which is known to the implementation code. Ex:

```
typedef struct SomeInternal* Handle;
```

It's critical to avoid superfluous SDK source changes and to make debugging easier to make sure this internal is named appropriately and in a way that is very unlikely to clash with another library. A prefix naming convention is useful here that you apply thoroughly throughout your SDK.

Now about abstraction cost, I used to worry about this a lot earlier in my career and my biggest suggestion is to always forget about it (for now). This is because the cost of an indirect function call is almost always estimated to be grossly higher than it actually is. Think of the classic `qsort` vs. `std::sort` example with the C++ `std::sort` generated for a type T often outperforming `qsort` by 2-3 times due to the lack of indirect calls to a comparator. This inefficiency in `qsort` exists inevitably here due to the runtime abstraction, but consider that it is often calling that comparator function many times per element (often around an average of 30 indirect calls or so per element for a million elements in various implementations I've tested). It's rare to come across those kinds of scenarios outside of a few select areas like this where you have a sprawling number of indirect function calls multiplied by the fact that each function is doing so little inside.

The other, bigger reason to forget about it for now is because you can always expose select internals as an optimization without affecting ABI or dealing with cascading source breakages when a profiling session strongly calls for it. You cannot do the reverse so easily, so it's safer to err on the side of opaqueness.

*If it is the case, how do I secure the lib in case API functions are called after close method which deallocates the data handle has pointed to?*

If this type of safety is a big concern (I'd generally suggest it shouldn't be a predominant one or else C might be the wrong tool for that job as the potential for pointer misuse is always present in the language in exchange for the raw power), usually you can set certain fields in the forward-declared, opaque structure inside a call to something like `close` or `destroy`, like nulling out a field in the structure to show that it is destroyed. Then you can raise errors if the client attempts to use an already-destroyed resource with the functions which accept an opaque pointer as a handle to that resource.